# ASP.NET CORE Kendo UI TextBoxFor fails to load

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo ASP.NET Core MVC controls.

I am using my form controls using `Kendo()` helpers like

```
 - Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x=>x.Title)
 - Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x=>x.TypeId)
 - Html.Kendo().EditorFor(x=>x.Description)
```

all controls works fine except **Kendo().TextBoxFor**, it throws the following error on console

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).kendoTextBox is not a function

Here is how my scripts and JS refereed in Head tag page

```
 <link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="" asp-append-version="true" />
 <link href="~/css/colors/green.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="" asp-append-version="true" />
 <link href="~/lib/flickity/flickity.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common.min.css" integrity="" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.metro.min.css" integrity="" />
 <link href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity=""></script>
 <script src="~/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js" integrity=""></script>
 <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js" integrity=""></script>
 <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" integrity=""></script>
```

Cant find any related issues online much.
Here is the full console error:

[image]

**Solution:**

---

Probably something wrong with my local Kendo JS libraries. Updated the scripts and CSS as below and all worked fine.

```
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity=""></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js" integrity=""></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does your kendo.mvc.dll reference match version?

Comment: Yes it is same version

Comment: It works now because you have to add first Jquery and afterwards the kendo lib :)